# Unity 3D: Not rendering camera when using Unity as library on Android Studio

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mapbox

I've successfully imported a project from unity to Android by importing the AAR. However my Camera feed is not rendering and the rest of the app functions properly.

I'm trying to integrate Mapbox AR Unity to my Android app. The app opens but camera does not. I'm getting this error code in my Android studio logcat on running the app:

```
(Filename: C Line: 0)
08-23 14:42:48.575 15689-15721/? E/Unity: DllNotFoundException: arcore_unity_api
        at (wrapper managed-to-native) GoogleARCoreInternal.LifecycleManager/ExternApi:ArCoreUnity_setArPrestoInitialized (GoogleARCoreInternal.LifecycleManager/EarlyUpdateCallback)
      at GoogleARCoreInternal.LifecycleManager._Initialize () [0x00019] in C:\Users\Tarak\Documents\MapboxtoAndroid\Assets\GoogleARCore\SDK\Scripts\Managers\LifecycleManager.cs:223 
      at GoogleARCoreInternal.LifecycleManager..cctor () [0x00010] in C:\Users\Tarak\Documents\MapboxtoAndroid\Assets\GoogleARCore\SDK\Scripts\Managers\LifecycleManager.cs:58 
    Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for GoogleARCoreInternal.LifecycleManager
      at GoogleARCore.ARCoreSession.Awake () [0x00001] in C:\Users\Tarak\Documents\MapboxtoAndroid\Assets\GoogleARCore\SDK\Scripts\ARCoreSession.cs:42 

    (Filename: C Line: 0)
08-23 14:42:48.586 15689-15721/? I/Unity: has extra
    UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
    UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
    UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
    UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
    FromAndroid:Update() (at C:\Users\Tarak\Documents\MapboxtoAndroid\Assets\FromAndroid.cs:27)
```

Here's a Github issue link I raised but didn't get a good reply from Mapbox.
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-unity-sdk/issues/977

Comment: did you got the work around for this?